# Cast a negative int value to WPARAM resulting in strange values

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to send an int value using PostMessage but getting strange conversions.

my integer variable contains value like -491838 but this line

(WPARAM)value returns a value like 4294475458. Whats the issue here and how can i get the correct value?

Comment: It _is_ "the correct value". Why are you casting to `WPARAM`? Especially when you have no understanding whatsoever of what it does? Programming by guessing doesn't work, bub!

Comment: Send a message from what to what? Why? For what purpose? What sort of integer? What range could it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPARAM is an unsigned int, you are converting from a signed negative number to a unsigned number.

If you cast it back to an int on the other end it will have the same value.

Comment: Not necessarily. The conversion is only well-defined in one direction.

Comment: On other side, on conversion to int throws ArgumentOutOfRange exception.

Comment: Alright, turns out the other side isn't even C++ so you're even worse off.

Comment: if you were to assert the size of the two types are the same, then reinterpret_cast then surely the data is guaranteed to be correct on the other side?